How to pass args to node launched from VSCode npm command?
I have a NodeJS app launched from VSCode using npm which has been working fine for running and debugging. I now want to add the runtime argument "--trace-warnings" for node so I can get more detailed info, but I can't figure out how to do this in my VSCode configuration. Here is my configuration:
{
    "command": "npm start --prefix ${workspaceFolder}/Site",
    "name": "Launch Site",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "node-terminal",
    "env": {
        "DEBUG": "1",
        "DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT": "development"
    },
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--trace-warnings"
    ]
},

I also tried using "args" instead of "runtimeArgs" key, but neither works.

Try adding an additional -- to it. e.g. "args:" ["--", "--trace-warnings"]. or "args:" ["-- --trace-warnings"]. The additional -- tells it that the argument should be passed on to the next child process.

Thanks @bvdb for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. I tired the extra dashes in both args and runtimeArgs, and also tried adding to the end of the command args, none of them worked. Also I don't know if it's the linter issue or actually an issue, but the liner says "Property args is not allowed" and "Property runtimeArgs is not allowed" when those sections are present.

what extension is giving you the node-terminal debug type?

When I initially setup my project and was configuring debugging I used this article: https://sevic.dev/notes/debugging-nodejs-vscode/ but seems maybe I should change my configuration to something more standard?

I removed "runtimeArgs" (and "args") from configuration because they're not valid with "type" specified as "node-terminal", and then added --trace-warnings to the "start" command under "scripts" in the package.json.
{
    "name": "site",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node --trace-warnings ./bin/www"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    <...>
    }
}

Alternatively, can switch to using standard launch configuration using NPM which is better documented, but still using the scripts section to define the runtime arguments. (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)
